# Error en estrategia de tradingview version 5

Tags: pine-script

Buenoos dias , tengo la siguiente estrategia de prueba en TradingView version 5 de Pine script, en la cual intento hacer que (importante solo en formTO velas heikin ashi) abra una operacion Long cuando en la segunda vela consecutiva alcista sin Low, y la cierre cuando haya una vela que tenga un Low o un Open igual o menor al de la vela anterior:
pero tengo el siguiente error:

*Error at 5:20 The arguments 'maxval', 'minval', and 'step' cannot be used with the input() function. You can use the input.int() or input.float() functions to specify a range of input data values*

Vereis, no tengo ni idea de pine script, esto empezando de cero con IA e intentando aprender el codigo, a ver si alguien por favor puede ayudarme. el codigo es el siguiente:

```
    //@version=5
    strategy("Estrategia Heikin Ashi", overlay=true)

    // Input para la cantidad de acciones
    cantidadAcciones = input(200, title="Cantidad de Acciones", minval=1)

    // Calcula las velas Heikin Ashi
    haClose = (open + high + low + close) / 4
    haOpen = ta.na(haOpen[1]) ? (open + close) / 2 : (haOpen[1] + haClose[1]) / 2
    haHigh = math.max(high, math.max(haOpen, haClose))
    haLow = math.min(low, math.min(haOpen, haClose))

    // Variables de estado
    var float stopLossLevel = na

    // Condiciones de entrada y salida
    condicionEntrada = ta.crossover(haClose, haOpen) and ta.haLow[1] == ta.haLow[2]
    condicionSalida = ta.crossunder(ta.haLow, ta.haLow[1]) or ta.crossunder(open,                         ta.haOpen[1])

    // Abrir operación Long
    if (condicionEntrada)
        strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, qty=cantidadAcciones)

    // Cerrar operación
    if (condicionSalida)
        strategy.close_all()

    // Actualizar nivel de stop loss
    if (strategy.position_size > 0)
        stopLossLevel := math.max(stopLossLevel, ta.haOpen[1])

    // Aplicar stop loss dinámico
    strategy.exit("Stop Loss", from_entry="Long", loss=stopLossLevel)
```

Comment: El codigo generado por IA es incoherente, tiene muchos errores y es poco confiable. La Inteligencia Artificial es muy util en muchos aspectos, pero no sabe codificar Pinescript (por ahora...) 

Por esto, TradingView y la comunidad PineCoders han decidido [no brindar soporte](http://tradingview.com/chart/TRAIA/XwwZ70ar-Our-take-on-AI-generated-Pine-Script/) para corregir codigo-GPT.